# How to get distinct values in one column with multiple possible values in the other?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to work out if this is possible, let me give an example. Would be awesome if you could guide me in the right direction please.

```
Table = names
--------------------
Marks & Spencer
Marks &amp; Spencer
marks &amp; spencer
```

What I am trying to do is to return distinct values where I have converted all & signs and changed to upper case.

So my query is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS name FROM names GROUP BY names;
```

However, what I would like to do is also return one of the original values, it does not matter which one, but I only want 1 row to be returned, like

```
Result
----------------
name            original
------------------------
MARKS&SPENCER   Marks & Spencer
```

Is this possible? Because at the moment, what I get returned is this:

```
Result
----------------
name            original
------------------------
MARKS&SPENCER   Marks & Spencer
MARKS&SPENCER   Marks &amp; Spencer
MARKS&SPENCER   marks &amp; spencer
```

Thank you for reading, would really appreciate the help.

==========

## EDIT

The query I am using to get the above result is:

```
SELECT names.name, T.result FROM names 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS result FROM names 
) AS T 
ON regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi')=T.result 
GROUP BY T.result, names.name 
ORDER BY T.result ASC
```

I am using PostgreSQL btw, which can do more than MySQL incase that changes things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the new name to get only one row and, as you don't care which original name appears, aggregate it with something like `min`:

```
SELECT min(name),regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS name
FROM names
GROUP BY regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is still room for improvement:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(upper(name), E'&(?:AMP;)+|\\+', '&', 'g') AS name
     , min(name) AS min_org_name
--   , string_agg(name) AS org_names  -- if you want a list of originals
--   , array_to_string(array_agg(name), ', ') AS org_names -- for pg < 9.0+
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM  (   
    SELECT *
    FROM  (VALUES
          ('Marks & Spencer')
        , ('Marks &amp; Spencer')
        , ('marks &amp; spencer')
        , ('marks &amp; speNceR + sons')
        , ('marks &amp;amp;AMP; speNceR & sons')
       ) AS names(name)
    ) name
GROUP  BY 1;
```

#### Major points

- Improve regexp:

  - replace `&amp;(amp;)*` with identical `&(amp;)+`
  - after use of `upper()` on the original, the 'i' flag only slows execution. Rather upper case pattern, too: `&(AMP;)+`
  - Use [non-capturing parenthesis](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE): `(?:)`
  - As you use a escape sequence `\\+`, use proper syntax `E''`
- Simplify `GROUP BY` with positional parameter, no need to spell it out twice

Answer (score 0):

At present you're grouping by the original field *(you can't group by a field in your select)*.

Do you want one of these?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  name                                                       AS original,
  regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS name
FROM
  names
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  name                                                       AS original,
  regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS name
FROM
  names
GROUP BY
  name,
  regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi')
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  original,
  name
FROM
(
  SELECT
    name                                                       AS original,
    regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS name
  FROM
    names
)
  AS clean_data
GROUP BY
  original,
  name
```

Comment: None of those, sorry. I want to return two columns, not just the one.

This is what I am using:
SELECT names.name, T.result 
FROM names 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi') AS result FROM names
) AS T
ON regexp_replace(UPPER(name), '&amp;(amp;)*|\\+', '&', 'gi')=T.result 
GROUP BY T.result, names.details5
ORDER BY T.result ASC

Comment: @KevinOrriss - Your original query doesn't have tow columns ;)  But if you just add the column, do you get what you're after?  *(Edit to add `original` as an example)*  If not, describe the difference between 'my' output and the 'correct' output and I'll edit again.

Comment: @KevinOrriss - For the benefit of others, could you put that query in the question?